# Javascript array argument doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I had a javascript code to generate values for a table in HTML after sorting the values. At first I manually entered the array of values at the start of the javascript  code. It was like: names=[tom,jerry,mickey,mouse]; grades=[10,20,30,40]; then sort them and write values in table. It worked perfect.

```
grades=[10,20,30,40];
var swapped;
        do {
            swapped = false;
            for (var i=0; i < grades.length-1; i++) {
                if (grades[i] > grades[i+1]) {
                    var temp = grades[i];
                    grades[i] = grades[i+1];
                    grades[i+1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        } while (swapped);
    for(j=0;j<grades.length-1;j++)
    myTable.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML = grades[i-1];
    }
```

But now I have to convert it to a function. I tried like this:

```
function table(names,grades){
var swapped;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < grades.length-1; i++) {
            if (grades[i] > grades[i+1]) {
                var temp = grades[i];
                grades[i] = grades[i+1];
                grades[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
for(j=0;j<grades.length-1;j++)
myTable.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML = grades[i-1];
}
```

But it does not work. I tried calling it like:

```
table([tom,jerry,mickey,mouse],[10,20,30,40]);
```

But it doesn't work. The table is empty. What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't seen a `do..while` loop in ages. Your question brings back memories of my `repeat..until` days of Pascal... psst! any error messages / can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Look at the console what is the error?

Comment: Hint: [Arrays do have a `sort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) :-)

Comment: The bottom part is working good, so dont mind the sorting and writing the table part. The only problem is that when i manually writed the array at the start, it worked but now even though i call the function with same array, it dont.

Comment: @user3179249: Could you please [edit] your post and show us how exactly you are calling the function (from where? when?). Maybe also create a http://jsfiddle.net/ that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I can send you the files if you want to see for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Table is empty. What is the problem?

We don't know, especially as you just said "*that part was working good*".

> The problem is that even after calling the function like this, arrays dont have the same value as before.

Sure, you have swapped the values in them :-) If you do not want to modify the originally passed arrays, you will have to copy them before. You can use the [`slice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for this:

```
function table(names,grades,table){
    var swapped;
    names = names.slice();
    grades = grades.slice();
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < grades.length-1; i++) {
            if (grades[i] > grades[i+1]) {
                var temp = grades[i];
                grades[i] = grades[i+1];
                grades[i+1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
    for (var j=0; j<grades.length; j++)
//       ^^^                     ^^
        table.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML = grades[j];
//                                               ^^^
}

table(["tom","jerry","mickey","mouse"], [10,20,30,40], myTable);
```

Notice I also fixed the output-loop and made `table` an extra parameter.

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I haven't seen a do while loop in so long that the output loop seemed like a broken mess of code to me.  +1 for pointing out the `i` issue.  That was probably the actual problem.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the do-while loop here - the bubblesort is working fine :-)

Comment: It's working right, yes. I was just confused me for a second, I haven't seen do-while since I was just learning loops in JavaScript.  It's an excellent example of how/why to use one though.